# How to delete admin users from the database?

Tags: magento-1.9

Can I simply remove them from `admin_users` in the DB or is there anything else I need to do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

correct table is admin_user

```
delete from admin_user where username='username'
```

you don't have to do anything else, username won't be able to login.

Comment: Perfect. That's exactly what I needed.

Comment: please accept the question if you find it correct.

Comment: This is not good and also very unpractical.

Comment: @Andre did you read the question?

Comment: Thanks @KonstantinGerasimov, that was the way I was looking for! In my case, a hacker created several accounts having the same email: cannot edit them individually in backend because "the email is already taken".

Answer (score 4):

you can remove unwanted users from `system > role> permissions > users`

Comment: This would be the safer and more logical option to remove an admin user. Modifying the database directly doesn't always end well.

Comment: Im with you - doing it from the databse is more unsecure, however, the question is only for database usage. Anyhow, to have this (better) answer in here will help future visitors of this site. Therefore, upvoted. Thanks for the input.

Comment: @Max glad that you got what you needed:)

Comment: This is the correct way of doing this.